# What does the notation $ [ i \neq k ] $ mean?

Tags: notation

I can't figure out what the notation $[x \neq k ]$ means. Here's a bit of context:

The formula is:
$Pr[A_i^k = 1] = \frac{[i\neq k]}{|k-i| + 1} = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{k-i+1} \text{ if } i \lt k \\ 0 \text {  if } i = k \\ \frac{1}{i-k+1} \text{ if } i \gt k 
 \end{cases}$

and is part of a chapter where the average expected time of operations of a randomised treap are proved.

$A_i^k$ is an indicator variable defined as $[ x_i \text{ is a proper ancestor of }x_k ]$ where $x_n$ is the node with the $n$-th smallest search key.
That probability comes up because $\text{depth}(x_k) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} A_i^k$ and $\mathbf{E}[\text{depth}(x_k)] = \sum_{i=1}^nPr[A_i^k = 1]$.

I have no access to the pages that explain the notation since I'm studying from a pdf of a few pages taken from a book.

Comment: I can't suggest one character edit, but I think in the denominator on the left hand side of the equation you meant to use $|k - i|$ instead of $|k - 1|$. Like: $\frac{[ i \neq k]}{|k - i| + 1}$.

Comment: @MarceloFornet yes. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It  is used like a boolean where $[i \neq k] = 1$ if $i \neq k$ and $0$ otherwise. Notice that $[i \neq k]$ is equivalent to $i < k$ or $i > k$ for numbers, which is the right part of the equation you wrote.

It is called [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) and in general $[statement] = 1$ if $statement$ is true and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Thanks. Never encountered that before.

Comment: It's called the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket). Might want to add that to your answer.

Comment: @AaronRotenberg thanks for pointing out, haven't heard about that name before. Added to the answer.